# Click Event on Select for Validation Issue (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, firefox

I have multiple forms on my page and I need an option from a select dropdown to be selected before the form can be submitted, I have the validation working in Chrome, Safari and Opera but in Firefox there is an issue: it seems to take the click of the dropdown as the full click event instead of the click of the dropdown and the selection as the event. So basically every time I click the select dropdown I get the error message, which I don't want. Can anyone offer any help with this?

```
$(function()    { 
    $('form').click(function()  { 
        if ($(this).find("select[name=packageOption]").val() === '')    { 
            alert('Please choose a package option');
            return false;
        } 
        else    { 

        }  
    }); 
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said the form doesn't actually submit, it just adds the item to a shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

try the focusOut event.

```
var hasSelection = false;
$('form').find('select[name="packageOption"]').focusout(function(){
        hasSelection = true;
});
$('form').submit(function()  { 
        if (hasSelection) return false;
        return true;
});
```